# ComputeExpression Date Formatting

Tags: json, date, einstein-analytics, type

Trying do do a basic ComputeExpression with a date type that picks one of 2 dates using a case statement.

Dataflow fails on the ComputeExpression step with this error message:

> expression data type (Text) doesn't match specified type for field 'Billy'

Both fields being referenced are standard date fields in sf.com.

```
{
    "action":"computeExpression",
    "parameters":{
        "source":"Filter_Opportunities",
        "mergeWithSource":true,
        "computedFields":[
            {
                "name":"Billy",
                "format":"MM/dd/yyyy",
                "saqlExpression":"case when Close_Date_Adj__c is null then CloseDate else Close_Date_Adj__c end",
                "type":"Date"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like wave related topic, you should add appropriate tags to get proper help.

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding the date fields with  toDate(). Perhaps it's also necessary to enter a formatString, depending on the data.

```
{
    "action":"computeExpression",
    "parameters":{
        "source":"Filter_Opportunities",
        "mergeWithSource":true,
        "computedFields":[
            {
                "name":"Billy",
                "format":"MM/dd/yyyy",
                "saqlExpression":"case when Close_Date_Adj__c is null then toDate(CloseDate) else toDate(Close_Date_Adj__c) end",
                "type":"Date"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_eql.meta/bi_dev_guide_eql/bi_eql_functions_date.htm

Comment: I surrounded the fields with toDate() but they all errored with "root cause: invalid date value 2017-06-17".  I added a formatstring to match the ComputeExpression Format and all records errored with the same root cause.

Comment: This is the new saqlExpression:"saqlExpression":"case when Close_Date_Adj__c is null then toDate(CloseDate,\"MM/dd/yyyy\") else toDate(Close_Date_Adj__c,\"MM/dd/yyyy\") end"

Comment: Have you tried yyyy/MM/dd as date format as well?

Comment: Update the format but it still gave the sames root cause error

Answer (score 1):

Had to play around with the date formats and "yyyy-MM-dd" worked.

```
{"name": "Billy",
"format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
"saqlExpression": "case when Close_Date_Adj__c is null then toDate(CloseDate,\"yyyy-MM-dd\") else toDate(Close_Date_Adj__c,\"yyyy-MM-dd\") end",
"type": "Date"
}
```